# What is serialVersionUID in java, normally in exception class?

Tags: java, serialization, serialversionuid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should I bother about serialVersionUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/why-should-i-bother-about-serialversionuid)

I am going through some exception handling code and i saw something named as serialVersionUID. What this uid is for?? Is it only limited to exception or can be used in all classes??? what is the advantage of this id???

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/why-should-i-bother-about-serialversionuid

Comment: This is a good, well-formulated question IMHO, but it has already been answered (mostly) in the link above. As for whether it is limited to `Exception`, the answer is no, it can be used in any class.

Comment: in exception we dont have serializable... then why its there???

Comment: @amod0017 java.lang.Exception implements Serializable, so any subclasses will also implement Serializable.

Comment: thanks Tom for the information.

Comment: @TomJefferys you rock bro.!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`serialVersionUID` is a field to define the version of a particular class while `seriializing` & `deseriializing`.. consider a scenario where you have a class `Employee` which has 3 fields which has been in production for some time (meaning there may exist many serialized versions of employee objects), when you update the class to include (say a 4th field) then all the previous class (which are serialized) cannot be casted or de-serialized to the new one & you'll get an exception.

to avoid this issue, you can use the `serialVersionUID` field to tell `JVM` that the new class is in fact of a different version (by changing the `serialVersionUID`).

`@Farmor` & `@Tom Jefferys` said pretty much the same thing, but with an example things look a lot simpler.

Comment: Well explained. And +1 for the example.

Comment: how does `serialVersionUID` avoid the issue exactly?

Comment: when deserializing java can only deserialize non-volatile non-constant (non-final) fields. since `serialVersionUID` is both static and final the deserialization will fail because the values of the field in class definition doesn't match the one in serialized object. This way the JVM can throw an exception instead of partially deserializing (or hyderating) an object.

Comment: you didn't connect it with "why it is normally there in Exception classes.". You should answer the whole question.

Comment: Requesting a little clarification: 1. So, if I update my `Employee` class in future, should I change the `serialVersionUID` value? 2. Should the `serialVersionUID` values be different for different classes, eg. for `Employee` and `Client`?

Comment: Isn't this metadata, would not it be nicer if handled at annotation level? And what would be the subclasses ?

Answer (score 8):

It's used for serialization, it should be declared in any class that implements `Serializable`.

It's effectively a version number the JVM can use to check if a serialized class matches the class definition you're trying to deserialize it into.

There's more information on it here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

Answer (score 3):

It's to determine if they have serializable and deserializable compatibility if they have the same `serialVersionUID` and both implements `Serializable` then they are compatible.

And it's not limited to exceptions only as you will notice eclipse is prone to put a `serialVersionUID` early in your normal java class if it implements `Serializable`.

Edited: Updated to include @Spychos correct comment about the `Serializable` interface.

Comment: This is not strictly correct. An object is serializable if it, or one of its super classes, implements serializable.